# Could not navigate to initial route error when changing browser Url Flutter

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I'm updating my code to use Navigator 2.0 and dough the navigation through `NavigationBar`'s buttons works properly switching pages and updating the browser Url accordingly when I change it manually it throws an error:

```
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/retailers"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.
```

Also back buttons is not working, and throws the `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`error.
Can the problem be that I check for `routeInformation.location` in my Parser?

## edit

I tried putting the switch inside the `uri.pathSegment.lenght` check checking on `uri.pathSegments.first` and the back button now works dough still throwing the `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`error.

```
if (uri.pathSegments.length > 0) {
      print(
          'Uri.segments.first is: ${uri.pathSegments.first}..uri.path is: ${uri.path}');
      // switch (routeInformation.location) {
      switch (uri.pathSegments.first) {
...
```

This is my Parser:

```
class AppRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<RoutePath> {
  @override
  Future<RoutePath> parseRouteInformation(
      RouteInformation routeInformation) async {
    print(
        'AppRouteInformationParser.parseRouteInformation called for ${routeInformation.location}');
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(routeInformation.location);
    if (uri.pathSegments.length > 0) {
      print(
          'Uri.segments.first is: ${uri.pathSegments.first}, uri.path is: ${uri.path}');
    } else {
      print('AppRouteInformationParser uri has no segments and is $uri');
    }

    switch (routeInformation.location) {
      // switch (uri.pathSegments.first) {
      case '/':
        print('AppRouteInformationParser.urlSegment switch case : /');
        // return CyclistsPath();
        return HomePath();
      case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /cyclists');
        return CyclistsPath();
      case '/retailers':
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /retailers');
        return RetailersPath();
      case '/map':
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /map');
        return MapPath();
      case AboutRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /about');
        return AboutPath();
      case TermsOfServiceRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /terms-of-service');
        return TermsOfServicePath();
      case PrivacyPolicyRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /privacy-policy');
        return PrivacyPolicyPath();
      case PrivacySettingsRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /privacy-settings');
        return PrivacySettingsPath();
      case CommunityGuidelinesRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /community-guidelines');
        return CommunityGuidelinesPath();
      case LegalNoticeRoute:
        print(
            'AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case: /legal-notice');
        return LegalPath();

      default:
        print(
            '### default AppRouteInformationParser.routeInformation.location switch case ## default: /');
        return HomePath();
    }

  }

  @override
  RouteInformation restoreRouteInformation(RoutePath path) {

    print(
        'AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path ${path.selectedPath}');

    switch (path.selectedPath) {
      case '/':
        // case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/');
      case '/cyclists':
        // case CyclistsLandingRoute:
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /cyclists');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/cyclists');

      case '/retailers':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /retailers');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/retailers');
      case '/map':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /map');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/map');
      case '/about':
        print('restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /about');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/about');
      case '/terms-of-service':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /terms-of-service');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/terms-of-service');
      case '/privacy-policy':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /privacy-policy');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/privacy-policy');
      case '/privacy-settings':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /privacy-settings');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/privacy-settings');
      case '/community-guidelines':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /community-guidelines');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/community-guidelines');
      case '/legal-notice':
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /legal-notice');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/legal-notice');
      default:
        print(
            'restoreRouteInformation  ### Default RouteInformation.location: /cyclists');
        return RouteInformation(location: '/cyclists');
    }
  }
}
```

I also noticed through the prints I set that there might be a weird loop when the app first loads:

Parser

1. `AppRouteInformationParser.parseRouteInformation called for /`
2. `AppRouteInformationParser uri has no segments and is /`
3. `AppRouteInformationParser.urlSegment switch case : /`

RuterDelegate

4. `RouterDelegate.currentConfiguration appState.selectedPage is`

Parser

5. `AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path /`
6. `restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /`

RouterDelegate

7. `RouterDelegate.setNewRoutePath path is /`

AppState

8. `AppState setting selectedPage to /`
   which triggers delegate build, so again

RouterDelegate

9. `RouterDelegate.currentConfiguration appState.selectedPage is /`

Parser

10. `AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path /`
11. `restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /`

Non expected prints

RouterDelegate

12. `RouterDelegate.currentConfiguration appState.selectedPage is /`

Parser

13. `AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path /`
14. `restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /`

As when a button is pressesed then I only get :

Button

1.`selected tapped is /about`

AppState

2. `AppState setting selectedPage to /about`

RouterDelegate

3. `RouterDelegate.currentConfiguration appState.selectedPage is /about`

Parser

4. `AppRouteInformationParser.restoreRouteInformation called for path /about`
5. `restoreRouteInformation RouteInformation.location: /about`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days of struggling I finally found the problem:

In main.dart build method I was  returning a `MaterialApp` with a `MaterialApp.router` as its `home:` instead that returning a `MaterialApp.router` directly and move all the `MaterialApp` configuration parameters into it.
Everything works just as expected now.

## wrong way :

```
  AppRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = AppRouterDelegate();

  AppRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      AppRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      color: Colors.red,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('it', 'IT')
//        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            print('Web device Locale is $locale');
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MaterialApp.router(
          routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
          routerDelegate: _routerDelegate),
    );
  }
```

## correct way is :

```
AppRouterDelegate _routerDelegate = AppRouterDelegate();

  AppRouteInformationParser _routeInformationParser =
      AppRouteInformationParser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: _routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      color: Colors.red,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('it', 'IT')
//        const Locale('es', 'ES'),
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          // if (UniversalPlatform.isWeb) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            print('Web device Locale is $locale');
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      // localeListResolutionCallback: ,
    );
  }
```